# c:forEach jsp print always same position

Tags: jsp

I have this code:

```
<c:forEach items="${[3,1,2]}" var="expire" varStatus="loop">
   <span >${expire[0]}</span>
</c:forEach>
```

i want always print the first element of array, like that

```
<span >3</span>
<span >3</span>
<span >3</span>
```

where is my error, because this code dont work. Thanks guys!

Comment: This is because you are printing value at `0` position so it will give you `3` .Instead change this `${expire[0]}` to `${expire}` and see